# Local DNS override under Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I want to be able to override local DNS, to resolv a specific host as a local ip instead of the public ip stored on DynDns servers.

Our current internal DNS runs under Windows 2003 Server. We have two routers with seperate internet access, one for internet access and the other one mainly for VoIp traffic. Like the image below.

[image]

We need voip.example.com to be resolved as 192.168.1.3 in the DNS server instead of the actual public ip mainly to avoid having to use the internet bandwith to browse the voip server from one of the PC's configured to use default router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new forward lookup zone in your internal DNS server named "voip.example.com". Create a single host record in that zone with a blank hostname and the IP address you want "voip.example.com" to resolve to internally.

Any other hosts in the "example.com" domain will continue to resolve as they always have.

Comment: Great I did it and it worked. Actually I create the zone for router2.example.com to resolved the local IP and since in dyndns voip.example.com is resolved as router2.example.com it works great, And i dont need to create a zone for every single host but just one for the router. Thanks

Comment: The router thing did not went well since port mapping on my router does not work from Lan side. But still having the actual voip.example.com resolved as the local IP worked like a charm.